# Does the number of irreducible representations of each dimension determine the group up to isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Perhaps this is a simple question, but I'm curious about it and have no idea how to even approach answering it.

I know that for a finite group $G$, one has the formula

$$ n_G=\sum_\mu n_\mu^2, \tag{$\ast$} $$

where $n_G$ is the order of the group, the sum is over all (finite-dimensional) irreducible, inequivalent representations $\mu$ of $G$, and $n_\mu$ is the dimension of the representation $\mu$. Moreover, the number of $\mu$ is given by the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

> **Question:** Is it possible for two groups $G$ and $G'$ (say $n_G,n_{G'}>4$ in order to allow for nonabelian-ness, as what I'm going to ask would be trivially true for abelian groups) to be nonisomorphic, but have precisely the same realization of $(\ast)$? Meaning: can they have precisely the same number of irreps in every dimension?

Comment: $D_4$ and $Q_8$ have the same character table, but are not isomorphic.

Comment: The number of irreducible representations is the number of conjugacy classes, and if the group is abelian then all irreducibles have dimension $1$ so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes : the [quaternion group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_quaternion_group) and the [dihedral group of order $8$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_group:D8) both have $4$ representations of degree $1$ and one irreducible representation of degree $2$.

Note that there are not many way of obtaining $8$ as a sum of squares : every dimension must be less than or equal to $2$, and there must always be a representation of dimension $1$ (the trivial one), so for a non-abelian group of order $8$ the only possibility is to write it as $8=1+1+1+1+2^2$.

Comment: Haha, well that was easy. I figured as much. (I'll accept the answer in a few minutes, when it allows me to.)

Comment: Just a side note: These groups are even a counterexample to the related idea that the character table (which contains more information than just the character degrees) determines the group up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one non-abelian group of order $8$. Since $3^2\gt 8$ and every group has at least the trivial character, so we can't have $2^2+2^2=8$, the only possibility is $$1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+2^2=8$$

Moreover there are two different abelian groups of order $4$ which have $1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2=4$ so the list of dimensions does not determine the isomorphism class of an abelian group.

Comment: Perhaps a simple follow-up would then be: what about for larger groups, where there is definitely more than one possibility of writing the order as a sum of squares?

Comment: (That's kind of the reason I avoided the $n_G<5$ cases, since everything is abelian, which trivializes the question in a similar way.)